# jQuery datatable: Get class and id of edited cell

Tags: jquery, datatable, html-table

I am using jquery-datatables-editable (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/) to manage my tables with jQuery, but what I need to do is when I edit a cell, I want to get the id and the class of the cell that I just edited. How can I do that? Here is a part of my code:

```
//creating the table
var table = $('<table id="mytable" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1"></table>');
var head = $('<thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>IP</th><th>Status</th><th>Last Seen</th><th>Pref. Smithers</th><th>Debug LvL</th></tr></thead>');
table.append(head);
var body = $('<tbody></tbody>');
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    //using xml to fill the cells
    var ip = x.item(i).getAttribute("id");
    var row = $('<tr id="' + ip + '"></tr>');
    var id = $('<td id="ip" class="' + ip + '"></td>');
    var ls = $('<td id="lastseen" class="' + ip + '"></td>');
    var nm = $('<td id="name" class="' + ip + '"></td>');
    var st = $('<td id="status" class="' + ip + '"></td>');
    var dblvl = $('<td id="defaultloglevel" class="' + ip + '"></td>');
    var prfsmth = $('<td id="preferedsmithers" class="' + ip + '"></td>');
    var lastseen = x.item(i).getElementsByTagName("lastseen")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var name = x.item(i).getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var status = x.item(i).getElementsByTagName("status")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var defaultloglevel = x.item(i).getElementsByTagName("defaultloglevel")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var preferedsmithers = x.item(i).getElementsByTagName("preferedsmithers")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    nm.html(name);
    id.html(ip);
    st.html(status);
    ls.html(lastseen);
    dblvl.html(defaultloglevel);
    prfsmth.html(preferedsmithers);
    row.append(nm);
    row.append(id);
    row.append(st);
    row.append(ls);
    row.append(prfsmth);
    row.append(dblvl);
    body.append(row);
}
table.append(body);

$('#service_table').append(table);


//initiating the editable datatable
var oTable = $('#mytable').dataTable().makeEditable({
    sUpdateURL: function(value, settings) {
        return (value); //Simulation of server-side response using a callback function
    },
    "aoColumns": [
        {
        indicator: 'Saving platforms...',
        tooltip: 'Click to edit platforms',
        type: 'textarea',
        submit: 'Save changes',
        fnOnCellUpdated: function(sStatus, sValue, settings) {
            alert("(Cell Callback): Cell is updated with value " + sName);
        }},
        null
        ,
    {
        indicator: 'Saving platforms...',
        tooltip: 'Click to edit platforms',
        type: 'textarea',
        submit: 'Save changes',
        fnOnCellUpdated: function(sStatus, sValue, settings) {
            //I WANT HERE TO BE ABLE TO ALERT() THE ID AND THE CLASS OF THE CELL THAT WAS JUST EDITED
            alert("(Cell Callback): Cell is updated with value " + sValue);
        }},
        null
        ,
    {
        indicator: 'Saving platforms...',
        tooltip: 'Click to edit platforms',
        type: 'textarea',
        submit: 'Save changes',
        fnOnCellUpdated: function(sStatus, sValue, settings) {
            alert("(Cell Callback): Cell is updated with value " + sValue);
        }},
    {
        indicator: 'Saving platforms...',
        tooltip: 'Click to edit platforms',
        type: 'textarea',
        submit: 'Save changes',
        fnOnCellUpdated: function(sStatus, sValue, settings) {
            alert("(Cell Callback): Cell is updated with value " + sValue);
        }}
    ]

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can offer some theories, nothing definitive :

### this

It's possible that `this`, in the scope of a `fnOnCellUpdated` callback. refers to the edited `td`.

### Settings

Maybe the `td` is passed as a property of `settings` to the `fnOnCellUpdated` callback, however the datatables-editable documentation is unforthcoming in defining `settings`. You could try exploring its properties.

### Other callbacks

[This page](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/wiki/EditorSettings) indicates that the `sUpdateURL` option will take a callback function however you run into same problem as `fnOnCellUpdated` - its `settings` argument is not defined.

[This page](http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/events.html) indicates there's a `fnOnEdited` callback, which may be useful though again, its arguments are not fully defined.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with the default `fnOnCellUpdated` function. You can however make a simple adjustment in the jquery-datatables-editable plugin.

I found an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/issues/detail?id=38) at code.google that gives a solution:
Change this line:

```
settings.fnOnCellUpdated(status, sValue, settings);
```

to

```
settings.fnOnCellUpdated(status, sValue, aPos[0], settings);
```

and that should give you the id of the row.

Because I needed the id of the table row from the html like this:

```
<tr id="46" class="odd">
    <td class="sorting_1">46</td>
    <td >0</td>
</tr>
```

I changed the line

```
settings.fnOnCellUpdated(status, sValue, settings);
```

to

```
settings.fnOnCellUpdated( fnGetCellID(this), status, sValue, settings);
```

and that returns the id of the table row when you call the function:

```
fnOnCellUpdated:function(id){}
```